# Python merging sublist

Tags: python, list, merge, sublist

I've got the following list :
`[['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g','h','i',j]]`

I would like a list like this :
`['abc','de','fghij']`

How is it possible?

[Edit] : in fact, my list could have strings and numbers,

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7], [8,'a']]
```

and would be :

```
l = [123,456, 7, 8a]
```

thx to all,

Comment: Are your `a,b,c` ect. strings? i.e. do you mean: `[['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g','h','i','j']]` --> `['abc','de','fghij']` ?

Comment: is merge means that `['f','g','h','i','j','i','f']` will be merged into `'fghij'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can apply `''.join` method for all sublists.
This can be done either using `map` function or using list comprehensions

`map` function runs function passed as first argument to all elements of iterable object

```
initial = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
result = map(''.join, initial)
```

also one can use list comprehension

```
initial = ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
result = [''.join(sublist) for sublist in initial]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
>>> L = [['a','b','c'],['d','e'],['f','g','h','i','j']]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in L]
['abc', 'de', 'fghij']
```